# Want to install windows software in Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon

Tags: software-installation, windows

I have some software that I run under windows XP but now XP will no longer have support after April 2014, I'd like to run it in Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon.

If there is no Linux Mint version of the software how do I get it to run on Linux Mint as this is the system I will be using from now on?

I'm not an experienced user of Linux but I'll try and learn, then help someone else.

Comment: What software do you want to run, commercial (give name), selfmade (what language)?

Answer (score 3):

There is a project called [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) that will allow you to run some Windows software under Linux. It works surprisingly well, I'm actually using it to run the Adobe Digital Edition software to read ebooks from my local library and it works near flawlessly, as far as I can tell.

WINE is typically in your distributions repositories so I would suggest using your distro's package management application to install it. It should be easy to locate, just search for "wine".

If you browse to the Mint Community pages there is a button on this page that you can click to install it.

- http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/wine

I'll just caution you that you need to treat each application as a separate situation, so one might work just fine under WINE while another might not work at all. That's the nature of using something like WINE to simulate a Windows system + software on top of a Linux system, for the sake of whatever application it is you're attempting to run on this stack.

Just be prepared for disappointments. Not everything will work flawlessly nor will it be as performant as it was on Windows, in most cases.